# Find out if a column contains a certain number

Tags: vba, excel

Right now I have a macro that loops through a worksheet that contains data about different machine parts performs various actions on another worksheet using that data.  Now I want it to add each part number to a column in a third worksheet, but only if it doesn't already exist there.  Here is my code for adding the part numbers:

```
Rows("1:1").Insert Shift:=xlDown
Range("A1").Value = cpn
```

I have the list spoted after each added part number. Is there any way better than a loop to find out if the part number already exists?

Comment: I'll be gone for lunch for the next half hour or so but i'll check in right after that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `COUNTIF` method. Just like this:

```
Application.CountIf(Range("A:A"), valueThatYouWantToSearchFor)
```

It will return the number of cells that contains this value.

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly! It makes the program take a little longer but it's fine.